# unexpected results for timediff

Tags: mysql

The timediff function does not work as expected. In the following example I am trying to calculate the difference in seconds for a period of 1 year.

```
mysql>SELECT 366*24*60*60 AS expected;
+----------+
| expected |
+----------+
| 31622400 | 
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>SELECT ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000:01:01 00:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2001:01:01 00:00:00'));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000:01:01 00:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2001:01:01 00:00:00')) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                           31622400 | 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2001:01:01 00:00:00'));
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2001:01:01 00:00:00')) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            -3020399 | 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect time value: '-8784:00:00'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** What version of MySQL are you using? It works fine on 5.0.22 at least. I just ran this query. see here

```
 mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2001:01:01 00:00:00'));
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2001:01:01 00:00:00')) |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                           -31622400 |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Did you [see here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31864)? It *may be truncation issue* because Time range is much smaller than the date difference that you have.

---

*Original Answer*

Use this

```
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2001:01:01 00:00:00');
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2001:01:01 00:00:00') |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                                                           31622400 |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is you're trying to convert a negative time to time-in-second. Swapping the variables will do the job.

```
    SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2001:01:01 00:00:00','2000:01:01 00:00:00'));
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2001:01:01 00:00:00','2000:01:01 00:00:00')) |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                                                           31622400 |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I had similar problems.  TIMESTAMPDIFF rather than TIMEDIFF solved my problems!