# Retrieving records with the closest (before and after) given date

Tags: php, mysql

Consider a `tasks` table with the given fields :

```
id | release_date | task_number
-------------------------------------
1  | 2012-09-01   | task_number#1
2  | 2012-09-07   | task_number#2
3  | 2012-09-11   | task_number#3
4  | 2012-09-05   | task_number#4
5  | 2012-09-21   | task_number#5
6  | 2012-09-31   | task_number#6
```

I would like to retrieve records closest(before and after) to a given date.

I know this can be done by using two separate queries.

But is there any way to retrieve the closest record in a `single mysql query`?

For example if the given date is `2012-09-11`, the output should be :

```
    id | release_date | task_number
    -------------------------------------
    2  | 2012-09-07   | task_number#2
    3  | 2012-09-11   | task_number#3
    5  | 2012-09-21   | task_number#5
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick I think - it uses [timeDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) in the order by:

```
select 
    id, 
    release_date, 
    task_number 
from 
    tasks 
order by 
    abs(timediff('2012-09-11',release_date)) desc
```

You could use the value you are entering as a parameter in your connection from PHP like this:

```
select 
    id, 
    release_date, 
    task_number 
from 
    tasks 
order by 
    abs(timediff(:yourDate,release_date)) desc
```

And pass it the string in the same `yyyy-mm-dd` format quite nicely.

Edit: Interesting comment from chops below, seems spot on accurate - however the following should do the trick as a workaround:

```
select 
    id, 
    release_date, 
    task_number 
from 
    tasks 
order by 
    abs(time_to_sec(timediff('2012-09-11',release_date))) desc
```

Comment: In my initial testing, calling abs on the result of a timediff call results in the same value always being returned regardless of inputs: 8385959.000000.  Try it: `SELECT abs(TIMEDIFF('2010-12-31 23:59:59.000001','2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002'));`

Comment: @chops Yeah, I did find that - interesting. Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780128/unexpected-results-for-timediff) it seems there is an easy workaround though :)

Comment: I believe we have to use `datediff` instead of `timediff`. I tried modifying that also but still it is returning all the rows and not exactly one row before and one row after

Comment: @BPRAM The dateDiff will only return the difference in days, so I went with timediff to give a more accurate `order by` However if your data is only date based, it could well work a charm :)

Comment: @Fluffeh ya I got your point. the thing is its not giving me the desired output. So I have decided to use `UNION ALL` function to combine the records with two different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have index on release_date, you can do it like this to earn a better performance.

```
select 
    id, 
    release_date, 
    abs( datediff(release_date,"$the_date") ) as sort_key
from tasks
where 
    id = (select id from tasks where release_date > "$the_date" order by created_time limit 1)      
    or 
    id = (select id from tasks where release_date < "$the_date" order by created_time desc limit 1) 
order by sort_key limit 1;
```

The first subquery will find the id of first date after $the_date, and the second one will find the id of last date before $the_date, after that, we can choose the desire date easily.